# Magento 2 Sales report customizations

Tags: magento2

How can I customize the orders report?
want to add few more columns and want remove few ones? for example something like following?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Today I received Notification I post question which has no answer with no comments :P
I had achieved this and forget this question Let me post question here for someone who want to customize the same report.
create module like:

[image]

di:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Reports\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Sales\Grid" type="Progos\Reports\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Sales\Grid" />
</config>
```

Grid havibng your modifications its just for reference

```
<?php

namespace Progos\Reports\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Sales;

use Magento\Reports\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Column\Renderer\Currency;

/**
 * Adminhtml custom sales report grid block
 *
 * @author      hassan.ali@progos.org
 */
class Grid extends \Magento\Reports\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\AbstractGrid
{
    /**
     * GROUP BY criteria
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_columnGroupBy = 'entyty_id';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();

    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getResourceCollectionName()
    {
        return $this->getFilterData()->getData('report_type') === 'updated_at_order'
            ? \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Order\Updatedat\Collection::class
            : \Progos\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Order\Collection::class;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {

        $this->addColumn(
            'increment_id',
            [
                'header' => __('Order#'),
                'index' => 'increment_id',
                'type' => 'number',
                'total' => 'sum',
                'sortable' => false,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-orders',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-orders'
            ]
        );



        $this->addColumn(
            'creation_date',
            [
                'header' => __('Order Date'),
                'index' => 'creation_date',
                'type' => 'date',
                'total' => 'sum',
                'sortable' => false,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-sales-items',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-sales-items'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'customer_name',
            [
                'header' => __('Customer Name'),
                'index' => 'customer_name',
                'type' => 'text',
                'total' => 'sum',
                'sortable' => false,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-sales-items',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-sales-items'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'country_id',
            [
                'header' => __('Country'),
                'index' => 'country_id',
                'type' => 'text',
                'total' => 'sum',
                'sortable' => false,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-sales-items',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-sales-items'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'shipping_amount',
            [
                'header' => __('Shipping'),
                'index' => 'shipping_amount',
                'type' => 'currency',
                'total' => 'sum',
                'sortable' => false,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-sales-items',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-sales-items'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'sku',
            [
                'header' => __('Sku'),
                'index' => 'sku',
                'type' => 'text',
                'total' => 'sum',
                'sortable' => false,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-sales-items',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-sales-items'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'name',
            [
                'header' => __('Name'),
                'index' => 'name',
                'type' => 'text',
                'total' => 'sum',
                'sortable' => false,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-sales-items',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-sales-items'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'total_qty_ordered',
            [
                'header' => __('Qty. Ordered'),
                'index' => 'qty_ordered',
                'type' => 'number',
                'total' => 'sum',
                'sortable' => false,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-sales-items',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-sales-items'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'subtotal',
            [
                'header' => __('Price'),
                'index' => 'subtotal',
                'type' => 'currency',
                'total' => 'sum',
                'sortable' => false,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-sales-items',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-sales-items'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'grand_total',
            [
                'header' => __('Original Price'),
                'index' => 'grand_total',
                'type' => 'currency',
                'total' => 'sum',
                'sortable' => false,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-sales-items',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-sales-items'
            ]
        );


        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportSalesCsv', __('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportSalesExcel', __('Excel XML'));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

custom collection in my case as I need differente tables and logic:

```
<?php

namespace Progos\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Order;

/**
 * Report order collection
 *
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Collection extends \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * Period format
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_periodFormat;

    /**
     * Aggregated Data Table
     *
     * @var string
     */
    //protected $_aggregationTable = 'sales_order_aggregated_created';
    protected $_aggregationTable = 'sales_order';

    /**
     * Selected columns
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_selectedColumns = [];

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory $entityFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report $resource
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report $resource,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null
    ) {
        $resource->init($this->_aggregationTable);
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $resource, $connection);
    }

    /**
     * Get selected columns
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getSelectedColumns()
    {
        $connection = $this->getConnection();
        if ('month' == $this->_period) {
            $this->_periodFormat = $connection->getDateFormatSql('period', '%Y-%m');
        } elseif ('year' == $this->_period) {
            $this->_periodFormat = $connection->getDateExtractSql(
                'period',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INTERVAL_YEAR
            );
        } else {
            $this->_periodFormat = $connection->getDateFormatSql('period', '%Y-%m-%d');
        }
            $this->_selectedColumns = [
                'increment_id' => 'increment_id',
                'creation_date' => 'created_at',
                'shipping_amount' => 'shipping_amount',
                'subtotal' => 'subtotal',
                'grand_total' => 'grand_total',

            ];
        $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            ['orderaddress' => $this->getTable('sales_order_address')],
            'orderaddress.parent_id ='.$this->_aggregationTable. '.entity_id',
            ['country_id','customer_name'=> "CONCAT(firstname,' ',lastname)"]);

        $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            ['orderitems' => $this->getTable('sales_order_item')],
            'orderitems.order_id ='.$this->_aggregationTable. '.entity_id',
            ['sku','name','qty_ordered']);

        return $this->_selectedColumns;
    }

    /**
     * Apply custom columns before load
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _beforeLoad()
    {
        $this->getSelect()->from($this->getResource()->getMainTable(), $this->_getSelectedColumns());

        return parent::_beforeLoad();
    }

    /**
     * Apply date range filter
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _applyDateRangeFilter()
    {
        // Remember that field PERIOD is a DATE(YYYY-MM-DD) in all databases
        if ($this->_from !== null) {
            $this->getSelect()->where($this->_aggregationTable.'.created_at >= ?', $this->_from.' 00:00:00');
        }
        if ($this->_to !== null) {
            $this->getSelect()->where($this->_aggregationTable.'.created_at <= ?', $this->_to.' 23:23:59');
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Apply stores filter to select object Also apply custom shipping address condition
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DB\Select $select
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _applyStoresFilterToSelect(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select $select)
    {
        $nullCheck = false;
        $storeIds = $this->_storesIds;

        if (!is_array($storeIds)) {
            $storeIds = [$storeIds];
        }

        $storeIds = array_unique($storeIds);

        if ($index = array_search(null, $storeIds)) {
            unset($storeIds[$index]);
            $nullCheck = true;
        }

        if ($nullCheck) {
            $select->where($this->_aggregationTable.'.store_id IN(?) OR store_id IS NULL', $storeIds);
        } else {
            $select->where($this->_aggregationTable.'.store_id IN(?)', $storeIds);
        }

        $select->where('orderaddress.address_type = \'shipping\'');
        //echo $this->getSelect();exit;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome this is what i exactly want THANKS
SKU Added but i want to add a custom attribute of product i tried same as SKU but its not showing thew value column is coming blank can u help me to achieve that